# In Spider-Man: Far From Home, is this superhero name a reference to another comic book?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, all of the characters travel in different cities of Europe, and Peter Parker doesn't want to be seen as Spider-Man there to avoid to reveal his identity.

So in Prague, he used another type of suit, but

> Some of his friends saw him, and Ned call him the **Night Monkey**

Is this some kind of reference to another comic book? Or is it just made up for the movie?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I thought of a possible reference  to *Journey to the West*, which is not a comic book itself but a major inspiration for the *Dragonball* manga.

Comment: Is there any Night Monkey in this story ? If yes, could you please write an answer with details, thus I can learn more about it :)

Comment: not to my knowledge, that's why I just posted as a comment. If anyone here reads Chinese well enough, they can check the original text for any specific mentions.

Comment: [Spider-Monkey](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-8101))?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Short answer, No.

---

> Despite a lot of Marvel's movies relying on the comics for inspiration, this time that's not the case.
>
> There is no comic version of Spider-Man known as Night Monkey (or at least not yet).
>
> It would seem that the name Night Monkey, which is actually a real type of monkey, by the way, is a creation purely for this film.
>
> <sub>[HITC, Spider-Man: Far From Home - Origins of Night Monkey explained!](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2019/07/06/spider-man-far-from-home-origins-of-night-monkey-explained/)</sub>

---

However, there is a monkey-based Marvel character named [Hit-Monkey](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Hit-Monkey_(Earth-616)), who is an assassin. More precisely, a killer Macaque with the skills of a master assassin.

[image: Hit Monkey wielding a pistol] 
 <sub>*Hit-Monkey Earth-616*</sub>

Quoting **Deadpool**,

> His name is **Hit-Monkey**. He's a hitman. Who's a monkey. *You don't believe me?* Look around you, dude -- he's real.

Unfortunately, Hit-Monkey isn't the character motivation behind Night-monkey.

Comment: When quoting from a web page can you include the link and indicate that it is in fact a quote in the future? As an >8k user I'd think you should be aware of this.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell Night Monkey is an entirely new creation for the film and there is no previous character with the same name. Executive producer Eric Carroll has spoken about the design for the suit and its inspiration but doesn't mention the name.

> While this particular stealth suit is a new creation for the MCU, drawing on the visual language established by the movies already, it does have some notable comic inspirations. “It’s inspired by a bunch of different looks in the comics,” executive producer Eric Carroll noted. “We have Noir, Big Time—but of course, when Ryan [Meinerding, concept artist and Marvel Studios head of visual development] was designing this, he has all the past SHIELD agents in mind, so it’s very reminiscent of what a Black Widow or Hawkeye wear. And it’s got all these little details, which Ryan’s amazing at.”
>
> <sub>[io9, Spider-Man: Far From Home's Stealth Suit Was Almost Too Cool for Peter Parker](https://io9.gizmodo.com/spider-man-far-from-homes-stealth-suit-was-almost-too-1834733458)</sub>

That said there is a character named Hit Monkey that first appears in a Spider-Man. Deadpool team up. However, this does not appear to be the inspiration for the name.

[image: Hit Monkey on the front of a comic] [image: Spider-Man and Deadpool talk about finding Hit Monkey]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

As mentioned [in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215661/in-spider-man-far-from-home-is-this-superhero-name-a-reference-to-another-comi/215663#comment589397_215661) there is also [Spider-Monkey](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-8101)) but like Hit Monkey he doesn't appear to be the inspiration for the name. You can see him in the below panel from *Superior Spider-Man Vol 1* issue 32 alongside Spider-Man Noir.

[image: Alternate Spider-Men including Spider-Monkey]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

If you want a bit of a stretch the night part could come from [Nightcrawler](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kurt_Wagner_(Earth-616)) as Spider-Man has interacted with him a bit in the past. And if you want to stretch that theory even further Jake Gyllenhaal starred in a [film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(film)) but it is unrelated to Marvel as far as I know.

---

Whilst your question was only about the naming of the character it is worth pointing out that the costume/suit appears to be influenced from Spider-Man Noir.

[image: Spider-Man Noir as seen in Ultimate Spider-Man]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>